# HTMLCollection.length returning 1 despite of having multiple elements

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, htmlcollection

I am getting an HTMLCollection after using below code in angular

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private el : ElementRef){}

const ele = (<HTMLElement>this.el.nativeElement).querySelector('.k-grid-table').children[1].children;
```

above code is returning below HTMLCollection in console but when I do **ele.length** it returns only 1 despite of having multiple tr elements
.
can someone please assist me on how to iterate over ele and why **ele.length** is returning 1??

[image: console]